# How to provide a generic url to jQuery ajax call from different directory of an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I created a http handler file in following directory of my application

[image]

I am referring this handler from `common.js` file using jQuery ajax and  `common.js` file referred in aspx pages `StoresSummary.aspx` & `EmoloyeeProfile.aspx`

From `EmoloyeeProfile.aspx` I am able to call the handler and getting the output, but from `StoresSummary.aspx` jquery ajax call getting failed.

I know the cause of failure because the path of `CommonHandler.ashx` file does not map correctly due to location hierarchy of `StoresSummary.aspx`.

This is a sample code I am posting, the http handler file I need to call from jQuery ajax and aspx pages may exists in different directory of same web application.

How do I give path of `CommonHandler.ashx` in ajax jQuery call so any location hierarchy of my aspx page can call it.

This is my code

**common.js**

```
function GetMessage(key) {
var message = '';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../../Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx', /*Working for EmoloyeeProfile.aspx but not for StoresSummary.aspx*/
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'MessageKey': key },
    success: onSucess,
    error: OnFailed,
    async: false
});

function onSucess(res) {
    message = res;
}

function OnFailed(res) {
    alert('failed');
}

return message;
}
```

**CommonHandler.ashx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace DemoWebApp.Common.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CommonHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class CommonHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string result = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(GetData(context.Request["MessageKey"]));
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.Write(result);
        }

        private string GetData(string Id)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString(); //just to demostrate
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**StoresSummary.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../../Common/Scripts/common.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Common/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Message" OnClientClick="return CallMethod();" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         function CallMethod() {
             var msg = GetMessage('001');            
             alert(msg);
             return false;
         }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EmoloyeeProfile.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Common/Scripts/common.js"></script>
    <script src="../Common/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Message" OnClientClick="return CallMethod();" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallMethod() {
            var msg = GetMessage('001');
            alert(msg);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide absolute path to the handler. You are providing relative path now. See the ajax url section.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx', /*Working for EmoloyeeProfile.aspx but not for StoresSummary.aspx*/
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'MessageKey': key },
    success: onSucess,
    error: OnFailed,
    async: false
});
```

Comment: This is correct. As an aside you can also pass as a parameter to the function the path provided by the .NET function `Page.ResolveUrl()` if you can't seem to nail the proper pathing.

Comment: Thanks @Bhuban, but this is not working .. call is failing for both the pages EmoloyeeProfile.aspx & StoresSummary.aspx

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta that should work if it is failing see what response you get after ajax error/failure

Comment: @BhubanShrestha, it is giving error in chrome console syaing Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js, but if i change the url to ''../../Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx" call works fine for EmoloyeeProfile.aspx

Comment: I have checked the path referring during call in chrome network is as follows for EmployeeSummary.aspx
http://localhost:50188/Employee/Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx

For StoreSummary.aspx
http://localhost:50188/Customer/Sale/Stores/Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx it is searching the CommonHandler.ashx under the same aspx page directory

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta you should put / character in ajax url. See the url in StoreSummary.aspx file and EmployeeSummary.aspx. both file is referring a resource in that location which is not available so 404 response you get.

Comment: Thanks  @BhubanShrestha its working now .. sorry for typo ..

Comment: @BhubanShrestha, When I host my application under localhost (Default Web Site) by creating new application it stop working, due to it does not refers application name before '/Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx' like this 'myDemoApp/Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx' . do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta instead of creating application inside Default Website in IIS you should create website and host there. You can add website by right clicking Sites folder in IIS then clicking Add Web site menu.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha this is not an issue in my development environment but my application may deployed on multiple sub domains there it will be an issue .. do I need to retrieve virtual path of url dynamically ?

Comment: then append your domain/subdomain name before /Common